# ios auto-renewing subscriptions, verifying receipt but get old purchase_date?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I verified the receipt like this:

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
/* send data to apple to verify */
```

and I got the json response as expected. the strange thing is I made a subscription today (June 5th) but in the json dict, the latest record I got is May 7th, like this:

```
 {
"expires_date" = "2015-05-07 15:25:33 Etc/GMT";
"expires_date_ms" = 1431012333000;
"expires_date_pst" = "2015-05-07 08:25:33 America/Los_Angeles";
"is_trial_period" = false;
"original_purchase_date" = "2015-05-07 14:13:35 Etc/GMT";
"original_purchase_date_ms" = 1431008015000;
"original_purchase_date_pst" = "2015-05-07 07:13:35 America/Los_Angeles";
"original_transaction_id" = 1000000152987263;
"product_id" = "com.xxxxx.xxxxxx";
"purchase_date" = "2015-05-07 14:25:33 Etc/GMT";
"purchase_date_ms" = 1431008733000;
"purchase_date_pst" = "2015-05-07 07:25:33 America/Los_Angeles";
quantity = 1;
"transaction_id" = 1000000154409972;
"web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000029706408;
}
```

any idea what happened? I expected to get the latest expire date from this verification, which should be some time to day. is it the right way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at _all_ the items for the most recent renewal? They accumulate in the local receipt.

Comment: I use [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL], is it the data source for all local receipt? the returned receipt json data is ordered by date, the newest one in latest_receipt_info is May 7th. subscriptions made after that are not showed

Comment: That's the right place; are you sure you're not mixed up on the iTunes test user being used? That is, the receipt in question is for the right combo of app and user that you performed the subscription under?

Comment: I think you are right, it is most likely to be mixing up the test users. by clearing up and doing a fresh installation and purchase, finally get the receipt from June. thanks a lot